# "Baker House" or "Baker's House" for combined business and home

Tags: possessives, attributive-nouns

I'm trying to say by this expression that I am baker and this is my home. This is the name of my business - cafe & bakery. And customers is like a guests in my home. Are this expression is correct? Or will be more correct Baker's House?

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting question.  If I understand correctly, this is your business but you want to convey that customers should feel like they are entering into your private home and receiving your very best baked goods, as if they were your own personal guests.

My suggestion is then to call it **"The Baker's House"**.  There are two reasons I wouldn't call it "The Baker's Home":

1. *The Baker's House* has a kind of nursery-rhyme feeling, as if it's something out of a children's book, and so it's already somewhat familiar and intimate.
2. *The Baker's Home* feels to me like you're trying too hard to be "homey". Customers might feel comfortable walking into someone's *house* uninvited, but not walking into someone's *home* uninvited.